# jquery.ajax multiple data requests through POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery.ajax to insert field in a table using php/mysql. I seem to have written a wrong code and a wrong syntax regarding the data: firld in jquery.ajax 
function. Can someone provide me with a correct way to do so.
The javascript is given below:

```
var degree_name = $("#degree_name").val();alert("Pass 4"); //build a post data structure
        var degree_school = $("#degree_school").val(); //build a post data structure
        var area_of_specialisation_degree = $("#area_of_specialisation_degree").val(); //build a post data structure
        var date_of_school_passed = $("#date_of_school_passed").val(); //build a post data structure

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:{'degree_school':degree_school,'degree_name':degree_name,'area_of_specialisation_degree':area_of_specialisation_degree,'date_of_school_passed':date_of_school_passed},//Form variables
        success:function(response){
            $("#responds").append(response);
            $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
            $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
            $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });
```

The corresponding *response.php* file is:

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
echo "I am here in response";

if(isset($_POST["degree_name"]) && isset($_POST["degree_school"]) &&     isset($_POST["area_of_specialisation_degree"])
 && isset($_POST["date_of_school_passed"]) &&   strlen($_POST["area_of_specialisation_degree"])>0 &&    strlen($_POST["date_of_school_passed"])>0
&& strlen($_POST["degree_name"])>0 && strlen($_POST["degree_school"])>0 ) 
{   //check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty
try {
   // create database connection
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    echo "I am here inside try catch response";
    // create new user
    $insertDegreeNew = insertNewDegree();

    if($insertDegreeNew)
    {
      ....
```

and so on. 
Please help me identify my mistake.

Comment: what an error you got??

Comment: Why don't you just **`serialize form`** and send it?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I am not getting errors of any sort. It just seems i can't reach the response.php file. I tried putting an echo but did not get any message

Comment: @GuruprasadRao $this.serializeAll() isn't working either :(

Comment: `$("#formid").serialize()` else use `var formdata = new FormData($('#formid').get(0));`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I have made an edit. Please give it a look. Was I doing it right that way?

Comment: Try opening the page in the Chrome. Open Network tab in developer tools (F12). Now fire the ajax call on the page, you'll be able to see the HTTP request logged in the network tab, there you should be able to see the HTTP error code that you're getting. Also does alert(throwError) show any errors ?

Comment: else try `stringifying` data to like `data:JSON.stringify({...})` and make sure you are not getting any errors in browser console..

Comment: @11thdimension I did give a check. And then I did get an error processing response.php file "undefined variable` dsn` in response .php".

Comment: @11thdimension so is my jquery right??

Comment: From the look of it it should work, if there's no Javascript error then we have to look at other possibilities, like wrong URLs, forbidden requests or something like that

Comment: What is $dsn ? Has this variable been defined ?

Comment: @11thdimension I am not sure about its validity, but I am sure of the response.php not being error-less.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao $("#formid").serialize() is working!! Dhanyavaad

Comment: @11thdimension its database server name. I fixed that error but inside the php file I find that my pdo object is not working or something like that

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)